# Why Form Test Fails While Using React Hook Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form to build a form. The form worked well but the test is not passing.

The test passes when I don't use `react-hook-form` and jsut pass onSubmit `<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>`. As I pass onSubmit with handleSubmit `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>`, it does not pass.

Here is my form
`App.js`

```js
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App({ onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data) }) {
  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm();
  return (
    // <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>                  <--- This works
    // <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>    <--- This doesn't work
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        placeholder="Email"
        defaultValue=""
        key="email"
        {...register("email")}
      />
      <input
        placeholder="Password"
        defaultValue=""
        key="password"
        {...register("password")}
      />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

And here's the test I've written for it
`App.test.js`

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

test("email and password field are clear for submit", async () => {
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn();

  render(<App onSubmit={handleSubmit} />);

  userEvent.type(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/email/i), "test@example.com");
  userEvent.type(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/password/i), "password");
  userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/submit/i));

  expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Working code is also available at https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-testing-olo4i

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`handleSubmit` has below the signature, as you can see, the return value of it is a **promise. It's asynchronous.**

That means calling it like this `handleSubmit(onSubmit)(e)` will return a promise.

```
type UseFormHandleSubmit<TFieldValues extends FieldValues> = <TSubmitFieldValues extends FieldValues = TFieldValues>(onValid: SubmitHandler<TSubmitFieldValues>, onInvalid?: SubmitErrorHandler<TFieldValues>) => (e?: React.BaseSyntheticEvent) => Promise<void>;
```

You need to use [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) of RTL:

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

test("email and password field are clear for submit", async () => {
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn();

  render(<App onSubmit={handleSubmit} />);

  userEvent.type(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/email/i), "test@example.com");
  userEvent.type(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/password/i), "password");
  userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/submit/i));

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }) 
});
```

If you do not wait for the asynchronous code to complete, it may execute after the assertion ends.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-testing-olo4i?file=/src/App.test.js:490-569)

Reference [source code](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/ee966378d16fa0f9d21ac1fa96d79c41a0e8e27f/src/__tests__/useForm/register.test.tsx#L110)

Comment: You saved my day mate, there is very little information about this common issue

Comment: life saver, I guess this needs to be highlighted more in docs