# Testing react-hook-forms submition fails

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I'm trying to do something pretty simple, when I submit a form, a function prop passed to the component is called. This works if I run the application, but when I run the unit tests it is always failing.

```
expect(myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected) 
Expected: "New Reason 1" 
Number of calls: 0
```

Here is the test:

```
describe("New Reason Form", () => {
  it("calls onCreate prop when the form is submitted", () => {
    const onCreate = jest.fn().mockName("onCreate");
    const { queryByTestId } = render(
      <NewReasonForm onCreate={onCreate} />
    );

    const submitButton = queryByTestId("submit");
    fireEvent.click(submitButton!);

    expect(onCreate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("New Reason 1");
  });
});
```

Here is the component

```
export const NewReasonForm: React.FC<Props> = ({ onCreate }) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => onCreate("New Reason 1");

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>Example</label>
      <input
        defaultValue="test"
        {...register("example")}
        data-testid="example"
      />

      <input type="submit" data-testid="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

I've been more than 8 hours trying to fix this and searching in google, but it looks like people that have had this problem already gave up. However it looks pretty basic to me, if I cannot test this simple functionality, how would I test more complex ones?

**Note**

When I remove the handleSubmit, it seems to work, but theoretically I shouldn't be doing that. From what I saw, handleSubmit only calls the callback if the form is valid. But my form does not have any restriction :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little bit I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69706522/7087543

TL;DR; Basically handleSubmit is asynchronous, so you only need to wrap it with a wait for like this

```
await waitFor(() => {
      expect(onCreate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("New Reason 1");
    });
```